# Programmatically controlling Grunt.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I would like to have access to the many available plugins and tasks in the grunt ecosystem to make my life easier, but I would like control over when and how each task is run. Most importantly, I want a way to run grunt tasks programmatically instead of running `grunt` from the command line in a folder with a `Gruntfile`. So I started poking around `grunt-cli` and `grunt` for a "way in."

From the source code of [GruntJS](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt.js#L56):

```
// Expose the task interface. I've never called this manually, and have no idea
// how it will work. But it might.
grunt.tasks = function(tasks, options, done) {
    ...
```

As you can see, Mr. Allman cautions us about the interface... my question is, has anyone gotten this to work?

My experiments, so far, have led me to believe the best way to programmatically control grunt is by mimicking the command line call with a child process:

```
$ npm install grunt-cli //notice no -g flag

// From runner.js
var exec =require('child_process').exec

exec('node_modules/.bin/grunt-cli tasks to run', {
  cwd: 'path/to/directory/with/a/gruntfile'
}, function() { /* do stuff here */ });
```

This seems dirty so I'm thinking about simply writing my own task-runner that exposes an interface for grunt tasks. However, I don't want to dup work if someone has had success with `grunt.tasks()` despite Mr. Allman's warnings.

Comment: This might be easier to answer if you give an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you... I'll add some pseudo code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious answer seems like it should be write a grunt task to do whatever you want to do :)

Then you can use `grunt.task.run()` to control other grunt tasks: http://www.gruntjs.org/article/grunt_task.html

You can also update their configs dynamically before running them very easily by messing with `grunt.config`

There's also this answer which may answer your question:
[How can I run a grunt task from within a grunt task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284556/how-can-i-run-a-grunt-task-from-within-a-grunt-task)

Also check out `grunt.task.start()` which is not publicy documented, but it seems to kick off all of the tasks https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/util/task.js#L246 (hat tip: @jibsales)

Comment: While this is good for running grunt tasks from within grunt tasks, I'm trying to avoid running `grunt` from the command line to initiate everything. I'm updating my question so this is more clear.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to avoid? Is it installing grunt globally? grunt is just a node program....

Comment: Hmmm... on second thought the links in your answer might have got the right synapses firing now. Hang tight, tests are needed.

Comment: You may even be able to just do `var grunt = require('grunt'); grunt.task.run()....`

Comment: Thats exactly what I was figuring... still testing

Comment: Probably will have to do something like call `grunt.loadTasks()` or `grunt.loadNPMTasks` first, but I bet it will work

Comment: Hazaa!!! You were semi-correct. `grunt.task.run()` doesn't run the task, only queues it. You have to call `grunt.task.start()` just as `grunt.tasks()` does here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt.js#L155

Comment: I'll mark your answer correct if you add the need to call `grunt.task.start()`

Comment: Here we are a full year later and I'm needed this answer myself :-p Will update, thanks @jibsales

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this would help you to write a custom handler : https://www.npmjs.com/package/rungrunttask

Usage details

```
var RunGruntTask = require('rungrunttask').RunGruntTask;
var taskname = 'some grunt task such as backup database every 24hours';
RunGruntTask(taskname);
```