# How to run other registered grunt tasks within a grunt plugin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm working on writing a grunt plugin that will help with a build process I use quite frequently. What I usually end up doing is copying/pasting my GruntFile from project to project, but I think it might be a bit more useful putting it into a plugin. The tasks that I use for this build process are usually grunt tasks such as `jshint`, `copy`, `cssmin`, `less`,  and `uglify` amongst others. I think I could clean up my `Gruntfile.js` file a ton if I could create a plugin that just took in some configuration and ran all of those tasks.

My current setup is usually something like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  jshint: {/* ... */},
  copy: {/* ... */},
  less: {/* ... */},
  cssmin: {/* ... */},
  uglify: {/* ... */}
});

  // Load and Register tasks...
```

but I would like to reduce the initConfig to something like this:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  build: {
    dev: {
      paths: {
        public: 'public',
        source: 'source',
        bower: 'bower_components'
      },
      options: {
        pretty: true,
        minify: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Is this something that can be done from within a grunt plugin?

EDIT:
I found something similar to what I was looking for, but it doesn't seem all that elegant, especially with all of the configurations I'll need to manually setup, but maybe it's worth it.

[How can I run a grunt task from within a grunt task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284556/how-can-i-run-a-grunt-task-from-within-a-grunt-task)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get things working with the solutions proposed on the other question that you linked there after your first edit. The point is that it still missing the loading of the tasks because their use case was not from inside a plugin.

I ended up creating a npm module wrapping my solution, you probably will want to take a look:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/extend-grunt-plugin