# Running a task from my custom task?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I am creating a custom grunt task:

```
grunt.registerTask('my-task', 'Do something', function() {
```

From inside this task I wish to run a grunts copy task, passing different destinations each time.

How can I run a task from inside my custom task passing different vars each time?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15284556/how-can-i-run-a-grunt-task-from-within-a-grunt-task

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing a custom task, you can take advantage of the API that grunt exposes.  You can run tasks within your custom task using `grunt.task.run();`

```
function myCustomTask(grunt) {
  grunt.log.ok('This is my custom task.');
  grunt.task.run('copy');
}

grunt.registerTask('my-task', 'Do something', myCustomTask);
```

You can learn more about running tasks within your custom task by reading this [API Documentation](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.run)